# Cannot Access the Help Pages in WebAPI Project which is deployed inside MVC Application in NopCommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, nopcommerce, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I have been working in nopcommerce and trying to implement the Web API Restful services for client application. I have added a Web Api Project and set the output directory of my WebAPI Project to the main startup project which is the Nop.Web Project. So Actually Nop.Web Project actually gets deployed and we have a sub-folder of webapi project in that main project. 
The issue we are facing is I cannot access the help pages which are generated for the webapi project. I couldn't Identify the issue. Please someone help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

Web API is currently implemented by Nop Templates and will soon go on release. Will work as a plugin. The plugin also has implemented a good reference. See how we are working on plugin it is possible here: [Branch Web-Api-3.70](https://github.com/SevenSpikes/nopCommerce)

Comment: Actually I have a added a seperate Restservices project and deployed it in Nop.Web so that I could access its services. I have been successful in that , have developed services now for the client application, But the issue is I couldn't access the automatic help pages which are generated in the WebAPI project. Either it give 404 not found error or " It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS." this error.

Answer (score 0):

If the help functionality has been installed as an Area  You will need to register the areas config in Gloabl.asax.cs

```
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    }
}
```